# About Linux Hugepage

Tags: c, linux, huge-pages

I used hugepages in my linux app, and I wonder if two different processes can share the same mount point of hugepages. Let me make my point more specific. I mounted hugepage file system this way,

```
mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge
```

In process A, I `mmap`ed `/mnt/huge` and in in process B too I  `mmap`ed `/mnt/huge`

Are there any problems? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Are you saying processes A and B both mmap /mnt/huge, or do they each mmap files under /mnt/huge? The latter would be the correct way to use hugetlbfs, and yes, it's fine for multiple applications to mmap files within the same hugetlbfs filesystem.

[This Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages) appears to have a lot of good information on the subject.

Comment: Thanks. They both mmap ed files under /mnt/huge. My question is if two instances of one application that use hugepages were running at the same time on the same computer, they would conflict with each other. I don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mmap the mount directory (/mnt/huge) - you mmap a file in that directory (e.g. /mnt/huge/one and /mnt/huge/two), therefore, there is no problem and two programs can both share the same mount point as long as they manage to create different file names.